# Adding conditions to Laravel has()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table named answers and its columns are `id`, `answers`, `batch`, `candidate_id`. I want to get all candidates that has no record of answers under batch number of 1.

Is there a way to add condition to this statement (this is in my candidate model) ?

```
return $this->has('answers', '=', 0)->get();
```

I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
return $this->has('answers', '=', 0)->whereBatch(1)->get();
```

Comment: found on documentation  
"If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries"

Answer (score 3):

You need `whereHas`:

```
$this->whereHas('answers', function ($q) {
   $q->whereBatch(1);
}, '=', 0)->get();
```

Btw this is exactly the same as calling `has` with closure as  5th param:

```
$this->has('answers', '=', 0, 'and', function ($q) {
   $q->whereBatch(1);
})->get();
```